# How do I get the string value of a node?

Tags: java, saxon

The XPath `string(/ROOT/Products/UnitPrice)` works fine in dom4j & the .NET runtime. But in Saxon it throws an exception of:

```
net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of string() (<UnitPrice/>, <UnitPrice/>, ...)
```

What's going on here? Why is this not OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the s9api interface, you can call

`XPathCompiler.setBackwardsCompatible(true);`

to make XPath expressions run in XPath 1.0 compatibility mode. This doesn't completely replicate all aspects of XPath 1.0 behaviour, but it will handle most of the things that changed between XPath 1.0 and 2.0.

Very often the incompatibilities that were introduced in 2.0 are because they affect areas that were a common source of user errors in 1.0. It's really best not to rely on the implicit truncation of an input sequence performed by functions like `string()`; it's the cause of many application bugs.

**==LATER==**

We tried to remove 1.0 compatibility mode in Saxon-HE 9.8, thinking that after 10 years few people would still be relying on it. Unfortunately those few made a fuss, and we decided to backtrack. But I've just seen that in HE 9.8, the setBackwardsCompatible() method will throw an error saying it's not supported. Try instead:

```
XPathCompiler.getUnderlyingStaticContext().setBackwardsCompatibilityMode(true);
```

Comment: Thank you. And we'll adjust the selects as we want to be using 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Saxon expects a single node as input.

The .NET implementation is different; it considers only the first one:

> The string() function converts a node-set to a string by returning the string value of the **first node** in the node-set, which in some instances may yield unexpected results.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256133(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: How can I change this to work in Saxon? We have a ton of queries that do this that I'll need to correct.

Comment: Can you update the question with a fragment of the xml and the expected result?

Comment: `string(/root/products[1]/unitPrice[1])` gives the same result, only taking into account the first element and ignoring all others. It is up to you to decide whether this matches what you want to achieve - maybe also the result of the .NET/dom4j implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is: `/ROOT/Products/UnitPrice` may return more than one result and XPath 2.0 `string` function does not accept more than one argument ([see here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-string)).

Saxon is XPath 2.0 compliant. To solve your problem, you can write this XPath expression:

```
for $price in /ROOT/Products/UnitPrice return string($price)
```

You will then have to iterate over the result ([XdmValue](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XdmValue.html) object).